# Publish ASP.NET MVC Application : read configuration file permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble when publishing an MVC application to a server, and even to my personal computer.

The server has the MVC framework installed so that is not the problem, and I also have it installed obviously.

The problem on my local machine is obviously a permissions thing but im not sure what permissions are needed... I tried adding IUSR to the application itself.

The iis error message is:
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070005
Config Error    Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File ~\Visual Studio 2008\Project\MVCApp\web.config

and on the server im getting "The page cannot be found" when trying to view anything in the app.

also this is a forms auth app that denys everything but authenticated users

Comment: are you running it on 2003 or 2008?

Comment: sorry iis 7.5 visual studio 2008

Comment: the server i'm not exactly sure on i think it's iis6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have wildcard mappings turned on so that it can resolve the routes.

Take a look at option 1:
http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Basically, IIS is trying to locate a file at the given URL, but it doesn't exist because they are MVC Routes. You need to tell IIS to hand off the request to the ASP.Net route handler, and not to worry about checking if the file exists on the file system. (it will never exist)

[image]

Comment: any notes about the other problem?

Comment: unfortunately i've never seen that one before. :(

I would move everything to the Inetpub folder (C:\inetpub\\) and make sure IUSER has permissions to that folder and all subfolders)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that upgrading an MVC 2 project to MVC 3 resulted in the sam error as described above:

> Module IIS Web Core Notification BeginRequest Handler Not yet determined Error Code 0x80070005 Config Error Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions Config File ~\Visual Studio 2010\Project\MVCApp\web.config

What solved the problem for me was to delete the Virtual Directory for the project in my localhost IIS, and then clean and rebuild the project.

NOTE! This was an MVC2 project in VS2010 - not VS2008.