# How to publish mvc3 applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm busy making a CMS using MVC3. I want to test the current build on the live server. Now, with a normal html website, you'd have a index.html or index.php and i think asp gives a default.aspx. But I don't have anything like that in my project. Can anyone tell me where to get a default page, or how to make one, I have no idea what the format/syntax would be...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606795/how-to-publish-aspnet-mvc-site

Comment: @J.Steen It is similar to that question but read it again, the title is misleading and a little different than that duplicate

Comment: @hunter, I'm guessing the issue at hand originates in the fact that the mvc application hasn't been published in the 'correct' way, which is why I posted my 'possible duplicate' comment. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407(v=vs.90).aspx

And a possible duplicate of this one:

[Publish ASP.NET MVC Application : read configuration file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521652/publish-asp-net-mvc-application)

and this

[How to publish aspnet.mvc site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606795/how-to-publish-aspnet-mvc-site)

Comment: I have followed those exact steps but the page just won't load no matter how I try to acces it.

Comment: That is weird. Can you post the snapshot then?

Answer (score 2):

The default page is defined by your routes and your views.

Look for something like `/Home/Index.aspx` which is what will be served up when going to **www.domain.com**

---

To do a simple publish use the **Publish** workflow by right-clicking your ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio and select **Publish**

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't. I have a `HomeController.cs` and within it is `public ActionResult index(){ return View(); }` and it all works well when simply pressing f5 for debug, but when I publish it I can't see the page in my browser.

Comment: You probably have IIS set up wrong. Is it running the right version of .NET? What version of IIS? You may have to create a wildcard for MVC to work properly on IIS6.